# Why is clutter not working?

Tags: debian, gnome3, gdm, gnome-shell

I've managed to install Gnome 3 on Debian testing. However, it is just running in fallback-mode.

When want to start mutter or gnome-shell, there seems to be a problem with Clutter:

```
# mutter --replace
failed to create drawable

(mutter:32069): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to select the newly created GLX context
Fensterverwalter-Fehler:Unable to initialize Clutter.

# gnome-shell --replace
failed to create drawable

(gnome-shell:32182): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to select the newly created GLX context
Fensterverwalter-Fehler:Unable to initialize Clutter.
```

(Fensterverwalter-Fehler is german and means window-manager error)

I know it's not a hardware-issue as I used mutter (and even gnome-shell on another installation) on this notebook.

How can I find out which setting is wrong or which package is missing?

Thank you in advance!

**[edit]**

Could gdm be the source of this problem?

Because I have gdm (not gdm3) installed. When I install gdm3 the login screen doesn't show me a field to select or input my username, therefore I can't log in.